# Caching android app webcontent and displaying the content when offline

Tags: android

I am creating an android application that fetch data online using json. I want to display the previous content if offline . Can anyone please suggest a solution for this? Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the HttpURLConnection everything is automatically cached for you. Check out http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html for details.

Comment: Responses are _not_ automatically cached for you. You need to to implement `ResponseCache` and tell the connection to use it. Note that docs for HttpURLConnection state regarding `ResponseCache`: "Implementing this API is onerous". (Only Ice Cream Sandwich makes things a bit easier.) Besides, this just brings the question around in a circle: how do you implement `ResponseCache` to do what OP wants?

Comment: Ted, thanks for the catch. I should've read the blog post a little closer. So yes, the question is now "How do you implement a ResponseCache?"

Comment: I imagine that OP would want the cached data stays around between app restarts. That basically brings everything back to how to use the data storage facilities.

Comment: i had searched over this issue and how about using shared preferences. I think that works well if we programme to take data from shared preference when offline

Comment: I really feel Ashish is either a lazy fellow or without senses. He is just blabbering .....

Answer (score 1):

You have various options. Read the development guide topic [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). I'd recommend using either storage or an SQLite data base. Depending on how much data you are caching, you might consider using external storage, just so that your app will be a good citizen on the user's phone.

Comment: This is probably the better response. I guess I just assumed you were going to only be caching a small amount of data. If you're going to be caching anything non-trival then this is definitely the best solution.

Comment: i had searched over this issue and how about using shared preferences. I think that works well if we programme to take data from shared preference when offline

Answer (score 1):

you need to use appcache for displaying the content offline. Android supports html5 appcache

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HTML5 features Application Cache, this is the easiest way for displaying the whole content of a webpage offline.

Comment: @aav ofcourse you can use it , android and ios webview supports html5 appcache.